# Diagnosing a HTTP 500 Error With Apache and HAProxy

Tags: apache, http, asynchronous, svn, haproxy

I'm running into an issue with an application I'm working on that has me completely stumped. The program is an iOS app that needs to be able to asynchronously download images from an SVN server. Users have been reporting missing images and when I dug into the code, I noticed that some of the downloads were timing out. I tried increasing the timeout on the request and adding code to retry on failure with no success.

Looking at the apache access logs for the web server, I noticed that some of the download requests were failing with '500' errors. The problem is, I don't actually see any details logged for those errors in the top level apache error logs or in the apache error logs for that site. Most of the information I can find is for people having issues with php, but I already eliminated that as a possibility. The error logging for php is enabled and I'm not seeing anything in those logs.

My other thought was that it might be an issue with the proxy server (haproxy) that is directing the requests to my web server, but that also seems to be working correctly. If I look at the line in the haproxy log for the failing request, it is showing status '200'.

Can anyone shed some light on this? The missing images are a major issue for my users and I don't know what else to look at.

**Update:**
I think I can rule out the proxy server as a cause. I modified the code to point directly at the svn server via the ip address and the results were the same.

**apache access log**

```
"GET /svn/mysite/33245/img/13301.jpg HTTP/1.1" 500 500 1 251118 "-" "MyApp/1.1.57 CFNetwork/758.5.3 Darwin/15.6.0"
```

**haproxy log:**

```
http-in backend_www_static/web01 21/0/1/3/1746 200 96024 - - CD-- 3/3/1/1/0 0/0 "GET /svn/mysite/33245/img/13301.jpg HTTP/1.1"
```

Comment: You've looked at logs, but have you tried to duplicate these errors yourself? If you can duplicate the errors you can start testing, say, the server separately from the proxy.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a production server so I can't just go shutting the proxy off.

Comment: Not necessary to shut the proxy off. Just test the backend separately from the proxy, either directly or with another differently configured proxy.

Comment: Could you provide some examples of how I would do that? Keep in mind there is no 'backend' that I can directly test, just an svn server that I am making GET requests against.

Comment: The svn server is the backed. Can you duplicate those queries with curl from the proxy server? Can you make another proxy in a similar place (network wise) and query through it? "privoxy" is a fast and simple install and configure.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually figured out that the root of my problem was actually on the client side. I was sending too many requests to the web-server at the same time and it was choking (see: [Incrementing a Variable from an Asynchronous Block in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52320986/incrementing-a-variable-from-an-asynchronous-block-in-objective-c) for more details). That said, I never did figure out how to actually find any relevant logs, so I will leave this open for now.